# Change paragraph spacing

Tags: google-docs

I would like to change the amount of space that is added when I do *Format* → *Line spacing* → *Add space before paragraph*. [It is possible to change this in Microsoft Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/adjust-the-line-spacing-between-text-or-paragraphs-HP010016523.aspx#BM3). Is there a way to do this in Google Docs?

Answer (score 11):

There is currently an option called `Custom spacing...` to do exactly that. I don't know if it was there before, but it is now.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No. Currently Google Docs has no option to change that. You can only use the predefined spaces.

**Update:**
It seems Google has added this option now. Look at @Zequez's answer.

Comment: Are there choices for predefined spaces? It seems to just insert a space the same size as the current font (is that correct?).

Comment: I can see 4 options.

Comment: Those line spacing options (1.0, 1.15, 1.5, 2.0) are not what I'm trying to change. Those are the space between lines within one paragraph. I am trying to change the space that occurs when you do "add space before paragraph" so that the space only occurs when you actually press the 'enter' key.

Comment: Still, no way to change.

Answer (score 0):

Well Googledocs is pretty useless in this respect. Worst case is to introduce a line feed and then reduce the font size on that line. One useful thing is that if you're using a numbered paragraph you can turn off numbering for your intervening line..... whcih you can then reduce the font on.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some screenshots to show our audience what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

This works if you have powerpoint online or for desktop. Download the powerpoint from google slides (file > download as > Microsoft powerpoint). Open the file in powerpoint. Find the slide(s) that have the issue. Then go to Line spacing options as shown in picture one. Then change the spacing. You can then either reupload the file to google slides (when not collaborating), or use import slides, and import everything (make sure no one has edited anything). You should be able to change the theme so that is the default, so new slides will be this way too.

[image: Option Select][image: Settings]